# SQL Aggregation of primary keys

Tags: sql

So I have two tables in my sample database:

Table #1:

```
PRODUCT_ID     TYPE    DATE    CONSUMER_ID
```

where `PRODUCT_ID` is the primary key.

Table #2:

```
PRODUCT_ID     ORDER_DATE    SENT     RETURNED
```

which contains possible duplicates of `PRODUCT_ID`

I want a query which returns :

```
CONSUMER_ID   TOTAL_PRODUCTS   TOTAL_SENT   TOTAL_RETURNED
```

Since I am fairly new to SQL, I cannot seem to join the two tables to get the meaningful data so any insight on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select consumer_id, count(t2.product_id) TOTAL_PRODUCTS, sum(sent) TOTAL_SENT, sum(returned) TOTAL_RETURNED
from table1 t1 join table2 t2
on t1.product_id = t2.product_id
group by consumer_id
```

Comment: Actually this counts the duplicate entries of `PRODUCT_ID` in the t2, what I am trying to do is to have the non duplicate entries from t2 yet still aggregate them.

Comment: count( distinct t2.product_id) does the work, thanks for the help :)